# Why shared_ptr<void> instead of shared_ptr<HANDLE>

Tags: c++, boost

Based on http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/smartpointers.html#smartpointers_shared_pointer

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> 
#include <windows.h> 

int main() 
{ 
  boost::shared_ptr<void> h(OpenProcess(PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION, FALSE, 
                  GetCurrentProcessId()), CloseHandle); 
  SetPriorityClass(h.get(), HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS); 
}
```

**Question**:

Why the `h` is defined as `boost::shared_ptr<void>` rather than `boost::shared_ptr<HANDLE>`?

FYI:

```
WINBASEAPI
HANDLE
WINAPI
OpenProcess(
    __in DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    __in BOOL bInheritHandle,
    __in DWORD dwProcessId
    );

typedef void * HANDLE;
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#pvoid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a `boost::shared_ptr<HANDLE>` would be a `boost::shared_ptr<PVOID>`, which is a `boost::shared_ptr<void*>` - which is, obviously, different than `boost::shared_ptr<void>`. Notice the extra pointer.

If you had a `boost::shared_ptr<HANDLE>`, it would essentially be a smart pointer to a pointer to `void`, as opposed to a smart pointer to void.

Answer (score 4):

Because `HANDLE` is already a pointer. A `shared_ptr<HANDLE>` would be a *shared pointer to a `HANDLE`*, not a *shared `HANDLE`*.